# jQuery selecting the right textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I got a little problem selecting the value of a `textarea`. Here's my HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <textarea name="notes" id="3"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="notesbtn" id="3">save</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

My jQuery code, where I try to right `textarea` with the id (the same) of the firing span-button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.notesbtn').click(function(){
        var jid = $(this).attr('id');
        var uid = <? echo $user_info['id'];?>;
        var txt = $('textarea#'+jid).val(); 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax/save_anote.php", 
            data: {
                jid: jid,     
                uid: uid,     
                txt: txt
            }, 
            success: function(msg) {
                // window.location.reload();
            }
        })
    });
```

But I don't get the val of the `textarea`. What is my mistake?

Comment: Don't use a number as the div id.

Comment: And IDs should be unique, else you can run into problems with any JS code that tries to get elements by ID.

Comment: here your textarea id like 3 and 3. and you are retirving it like 
$('textarea#'+jid).val();

Comment: and also id should be unique.

Comment: yes,my mistake to set more as one id!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use identifiers that start with a number.

Do not use the same identifier twice. They should be unique.

**HTML**:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <textarea name="notes" id="textarea-3"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td><span class="notesbtn" data-id="3">save</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**JS**:

```
$('.notesbtn').click(function () {
    var jid = $(this).data('id');
    var uid = <? echo $user_info['id']; ?>;
    var txt = $('#textarea-' + jid).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/save_anote.php",
        data: {
            jid: jid,
            uid: uid,
            txt: txt
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            // window.location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L6ZRr/1/

Comment: If your answer doesn't answer the question/address the problem then please post it as a comment.

Comment: What do you mean by rel="3"? It is not a link, and "3" is not a relation of any kind.

Comment: Andreas, you are right. I changed it to data-id. Rel is not a semantic choice there at all.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me a lot.. the other guys are right too, but this is only a little snippet of the whole doc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant set id only numbers. Try this

```
<tr><td><textarea name="notes" id="a3"></textarea></td><td><span class="notesbtn" rel="3">save</span></td></tr>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.notesbtn').click(function(){
        var jid = $(this).attr('rel');
        var uid = <? echo $user_info['id'];?>;
        var txt = $('textarea#a'+jid).val(); 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax/save_anote.php", 
            data: {jid,uid,txt}, 
             success: function(msg) {
                     //window.location.reload();
            }
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

id should be unique.

Rewrite your code to:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <textarea name="notes" id="textarea3"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="notesbtn" id="3">save</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

as you are retrieving it like

```
var txt = $('textarea#'+jid).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have gone through your code you are using same id but id should be unique.Anyhow i have created a example using your code..

javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.notesbtn').click(function(){
        var jid = $(this).attr('id'); 
        var txt = $('textarea#'+jid).val(); 
        alert(txt); 
    }); 
});
```

see the working example:-
http://jsfiddle.net/daL6s/19/

Answer (score 0):

As correctly noted in other answers: firstly, id should be unique and secondary, avoid id started from numbers. Additionally typical approach for your question is to provide user data via `data-` attributes, so html would be:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <textarea name="notes" id="textarea3"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="notesbtn" data-textarea="#textarea3">save</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and JavaScript:

```
// var jid = $(this).attr('id');
var txt = $($(this).data('textarea')).val();
```

see [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for details